# Can tensorflow lite parallel execut a multi-branch model?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I have a multi-branch model, and I want to run it on Android unsing TensorFlow Lite, I hope to parallel execute it, that is, one branch execute on CPU, and another branch execute on GPU, but it seems that TensorFlow Lite don't support this request... What should I do?

Comment: Do you know if the branches run sequentially? If so how did you find out?

Comment: When I check my multi-branch model in Netron both branches appear parallel to each other visually